# Can I use Public API?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, google-play

My question is simple , Can I use API from example [devresourc.es](https://devresourc.es/) or [rapidapi.com](https://rapidapi.com/) (which is public API) to developed my Android App(Let's say it contains Ads) and published it in Google Play.

Comment: it will be free up to 50 or 100 users only. if you exceed the limit you have to pay them. before using any free API there will be a documentation with it. you can read their policies and pricing.